# Yarn getting package.json location to use it in scripts

Tags: yarnpkg

I am getting some issues running a script from Yarn. I need to run the script from a project subfolder and getting access to the folder that contains the `package.json`

This is the folder structure:

- package.json
- src

  - module1
  - module2

If I run `yarn myscript` from the module2 folder I will get access to env variable INIT_CWD (the location where I run the command) but there is no information on the location of `package.json`.
The script in yarn is something like:

```
node --inspect $(which serverless) offline \
     --dbHost localhost --noAuth \
     --location $HERE_IS_WHERE_THE_INFO_IS NEEDED"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is possible to use the $PWD variable as it is filled with the package.json location, even if you run yarn "script" from a subfolder